# maven-replace-plugin to replace multiple tokens in multiple input files

Tags: maven, maven-replacer-plugin

We are working with two DBs (oracle and sqlserver) and want to replace ***componentPrefix*** for both DB files. But the ***semicolon*** only on Oracle. How can we achieve it?

Here is my pom:

```
               <execution>
                    <id>replace-tablename-prefix-tokens</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <inputFilePattern>oracle/updates/*.sql</inputFilePattern>
                            <inputFilePattern>sqlserver/updates/*.sql</inputFilePattern>
                        </includes>
                        <basedir>${dbdeploy.support.unpack.dir}/db/source_scripts/</basedir>
                        <replacements>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>@componentPrefix@</token>
                                <value>${db.prefix.am.tablename}</value>
                            </replacement>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>;</token>
                                <value>/</value>
                            </replacement>
                        </replacements>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you have in oracle/upcates/*.sql files already replaced the semicolon by slash?

On the other hand, you can have two executions of a plugin:

```
           <execution>
                <id>replace-tablename-prefix-tokens</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>replace</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <inputFilePattern>oracle/updates/*.sql</inputFilePattern>
                        <inputFilePattern>sqlserver/updates/*.sql</inputFilePattern>
                    </includes>
                    <basedir>${dbdeploy.support.unpack.dir}/db/source_scripts/</basedir>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>@componentPrefix@</token>
                            <value>${db.prefix.am.tablename}</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

           <execution>
                <id>replace-oracle</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>replace</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <inputFilePattern>oracle/updates/*.sql</inputFilePattern>
                    </includes>
                    <basedir>${dbdeploy.support.unpack.dir}/db/source_scripts/</basedir>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>;</token>
                            <value>/</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
```

Comment: These oracle files are generated by a client lib which generates scripts with semicolon. So we need to replace this part

Comment: Ok, but Oracle slash is for "commit buffer" on plsql blocks, and semicolon is valid for end update commands... but ok.